# Check if std::thread is still running

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is there a way to determine if a thread is still running? I cannot use `std::future` and `std::async` for several reasons.

I thought of some kind of `join` with timeout, e.g. try to join a thread for 3 seconds, if it succeeds, the thread is considered finished, otherwise it is considered running.

Comment: I guess you want `joinable`. Look up the documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/joinable/

Comment: If the function object invoked by the thread is under your control, the simplest option is to set a flag associated with the `std::thread` when the thread finishes. Checking if the thread is still alive would then simply check the current state of the flag.

Comment: But `joinable` will only tell me if the thread is joinable or not. Even when the thread has finished execution. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @user4815162342: I came up with that solution, too. I should have stated in my question that there are many many threads running (its a server application, each client has an own thread)

Comment: Many threads should not be a problem in itself - after all, you only need a single bit of state per thread. The problem is if clients are creating threads without your being aware of it - but in that case, how are you getting their `std::thread` handles?

Comment: I have a pointer to every thread that has been created...

Comment: If you can't modify the code that creates the threads, or the functions they are running, only having access to the pointers is not very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is [`std::thread::joinable()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable). To cite from the reference:

> Checks if the thread object identifies an active thread of execution. Specifically, returns `true` if `get_id() != std::thread::id()`. So a default constructed `thread` is not joinable.
>   A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

Comment: This will not work reliably since a `std::thread` that has finished executing but was not yet detached or joined is still joinable. You even cited this fact.